# How to encode FIRST & FOLLOW sets inside a compiler

Tags: grammar, recursive-descent, compiler-construction

I am writing a compiler for a compiler design course that I am taking and I am currently at the Syntax Analysis where I need to write a parser.

I need to have the FIRST and FOLLOW sets to handle any errors that may appear in the source text. I have precalculated the FIRST and FOLLOW sets for all of the non-terminals in my grammar but I am having trouble deciding where I should actually encode them inside of my program.

Should I place them in a map where the key is the name of the non-terminal?

Any advice would be helpful

This post may seem a little unclear, I can clarify any points if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep them, you want to attach them to the nonterminals they represent.  You probably also want an inversion, e.g., a map from set members back to the nonterminals of which they are the FIRST or FOLLOW.

Then you error recovery routine can use previous or more likely the "next" input token (that's the one which caused you report an error) to decide what you might insert into the input stream instead.

I don't actually store these.  I use a GLR parser, whose parse tables are essentially LALR parse tables, and simply build a recursive algorithm to crawl over the tables to see what tokens might allow the parser to proceed.  Indirectly, I'm taking advantage of FIRST and FOLLOW, since those were used to construct the parse tables.

If you are taking a compiler design course, I'm recommend focusing on the post-parsing issues.  You can sink tons of time into trying to "patch up" the source in response to an error, and all you'll learn is that a) this is hard, and b) nobody will particularly like the choice you offer them.  You can spend energy on syntax repair until you're blue in the face but I'd wait until somebody asked you to do it for a job.  In the meantime, for a compiler class, I'd let my compiler simply say, "Syntax error on line N" and abort.
Crummy but good enough to let you get on with the more interesting part.

Comment: While processing Syntax errors I would also like to stop at the first encountered error, because obviously the user needs to repair that before compilation will succeed; but a requirement for this project is that I must gather all syntax errors before reporting them to the user.

Comment: Could you explain more about the inversion? Is that basically a mapping from all terminal symbols in the first and follow of some non-terminal X? Also thanks for your response it was very helpful.

Comment: @Hunter: "gather all syntax errors?"  That's a little vague, because once you've patched your input so the parser can proceed, you've guessed what the programmer actually intended, and guessing is never right. So often, once your parser proceeds, it will encounter another ("cascaded") syntax error... is this one the user made, or one caused by your error recovery?  A cheap trick: if an input token isn't acceptable, report a syntax error, delete it, and move on (you might suppress additional syntax errors that occur in the same place).  ...

Comment: @Hunter: second cheap (better) trick: designate certain nonterminals in your grammar as "recovery points" (e.g, "statement").  Determine LAST(statement) similar to how you compute FIRST.  When you get a syntax error, look back up the stack until you find a place that can shift on one of the error recovery nonterminals, say S (for "statement").  Cauterize the stack back to that place; skip input tokens until you hit LAST(S) and throw it away, now pretend you saw an S and continue normal parsing.  This will skip the body of a "statement" by scanning for ';' if your language is C-like.

Comment: I am following a paper that is making the claim that if I encounter a syntax error I should skip input symbols until I reach a symbol from which compilation could potentially resume, i.e. a symbol in the FOLLOW of the current production being applied. It is still a guess as you mentioned, but as part of the requirements I need to record all of those cascading syntax errors and report them to the user.

Comment: @Hunter: inversion: yes, you want a map from terminals (and perhaps nonterminals) in FIRST and FOLLOW sets, back to the nonterminal to which they belong.  This is an educated bet you will find this useful, since I've never done this myself; I prefer my table scanning trick.  Since the table scan works and takes advantage of FIRST and FOLLOW, I assume if you think about it hard enough, you'll know which way (maybe both) you want to store these sets to store your error recovery.

Comment: @Hunter: the paper tells you to hunt for a FOLLOW symbol?  ... Sounds reasonable, that would be the one after LAST(S) so I guess that's equivalent, and if you have FOLLOW I guess that's convenient.

Comment: @Hunter: You're welcome, this is a fun topic (I only get to do this once a decade :)  ... improvement on second cheap trick: scan up the stack, determine all symbols (terminals T or nonterminals N) on which some stack entry could shift. Form the set  R=T union FOLLOW(N); this set contains input terminals which can be recovery points.  Starting with your error terminal E, repeat:  E in R? no, fetch next token call it E, repeat. At the end of the loop. you can recover at E at some point in the stack, cauterize and proceed. (Might be pretty close to what your paper says).